# How to combine ion-refresher and ion-infinite-scroll?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this so far and it is working horrible, everytime I go to the bottom of the page, it reloads and throw me back to the top

```
  <ion-content>
    <ion-refresher
      on-refresh="doRefresh()">
    </ion-refresher>
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
      <a ng-href="#/tabs/news/{{post.site_ID}}/{{post.ID}}">
        <h2 ng-bind-html="post.title"></h2>
        <p>{{:: post.date | date}}</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <ion-infinite-scroll
            on-infinite="loadMore()"
            distance="1%">
     </ion-infinite-scroll>
  </ion-content>
```

and the controller

```
.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading,
                                 $stateParams, FreshlyPressed) {

  $scope.posts = [];

  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    $scope.posts = FreshlyPressed.getBlogs($scope);
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
  },

  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    $scope.posts = FreshlyPressed.getBlogs($scope);
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
  }
  $scope.doRefresh();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you're broadcasting `infinteScrollComplete` and `refreshComplete` before they are actually completed. Those appear to be asynchronous requests, but you're responding as though they are synchronous.

This is what is really happening:

```
$scope.posts = FreshlyPress.getBlogs($scope); // call goes out
$scope.$broadcast(etc); // call is still out, this is too early

// (call comes back at a variable time, $broadcast needs to occur at that time)
```

To handle this, you need either a callback or a promise, depending on the api of your `getBlogs` function. It looks like `getBlogs` is doing a bit of magic to either add its result to $scope internally or it returns an empty array/object and then populates it when the result comes in. Either way, that is breaking the Single Responsibility Principle. `getBlogs` should just return the data in a callback/promise and let the controller decide would to do with that data.

```
var limit = 10; // max results
var offset = 0; // starting index
$scope.posts = []; // add results here as they come in
$scope.loadMore = function() {
  FreshlyPressed.getBlogs(limit, offset).then(function(results) {
    $scope.posts = $scope.posts.concat(results); // add results
    offset = $scope.posts.length; // adjust offset for next query
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
  });
}; // <-- you also had a comma here
```

For the refresh, you would just reset the state:

```
$scope.posts = []; // empty results
offset = 0; // start back at first post
```

And now you can load more posts just like before.